# How do I format the output of a nested JSON object with JSON.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

First, this has been asked a number of times but having read all the posts I found none provided an answer that fixed my particular scenario.

Also, please forgive any incorrect terminology as I may be misusing terms...

I am trying to take the JSON from this query and simply output to a textblock:

http://www.imdb.com/xml/find?json=1&nr=1&nm=on&q=jeniffer+garner

Which produces this:

```
 {
  "name_approx":[
    {
      "id":"nm0004950",
      "title":"",
      "name":"Jennifer Garner",
      "description":"Actress, Dallas Buyers Club"
    },
//more code
{
  "id":"nm3144518",
  "title":"",
  "name":"Jennifer Varner",
  "description":"Self, THS Investigates: Hot for Student"
}]}
```

The code I'm trying to use for this as follows.

Classes:

```
public class Movie
{
    public List<Stream> name_approx { get; set; }

    public Movie ()
    {}
}

public class Stream 
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }

    public Stream ()
    {}
}
```

and...

```
searchOutput.Text = "";
searchStatusOutput.Text = "Awaiting Response...";
string userURI = inputAddress.Text;

var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(userURI);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Movie output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(content);

//searchOutput.Text = ??????
```

When I run this I can see that **Movie Output** correctly contains one *'name_approx'* object and nested within it 20 *'Streams'* as I expect.

I cannot however figure out how to output this to my text block. I've tried numerous approaches and think I need to use some form of foreach however I'm stuck and cannot work it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have it as a Json object, you could serialize the parent object back to a formatted Json string and display it in <pre> tags to keep the formatting.

Json.Net has a method for this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movieObject, Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been trying for 3 hours to do this myself before I posted here.

Comment: No worries mate, if your going to be using this library check out the documentation as its a very powerful.